# Installation problem linuxmint 13 Maya, invisible mouse

Tags: linux-mint, mouse

I was installed Linux Mint 13 maya to my mother's PC. Unfortunately the mouse is working "invisible mode", it works but I can't see the arrow. The problem is same when I boot from liveCD. This liveCD works perfect in my other computer.